# Writing small amount of data to large number of files on GlusterFS 3.7

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, glusterfs

I'm experimenting with 2 Gluster 3.7 servers in 1x2 configuration. Servers are connected over 1 Gbit network. I'm using Debian Jessie.

My use case is as follows: **open file -> append 64 bytes -> close file** and do this in a loop for about 5000 different files. Execution time for such loop is roughly 10 seconds if I access files through mounted glusterfs drive. If I use **libgfsapi** directly, execution time is about 5 seconds (2 times faster).

However, the same loop executes in 50ms on plain ext4 disk.

There is huge performance difference between Gluster 3.7 end earlier versions which is, I believe, due to the **cluster.eager-lock** setting.

My target is to execute the loop in less than 1 second.

I've tried to experiment with lots of Gluster settings but without success. **dd** tests with various bsize values behave like that **TCP no-delay option** is not set, although from Gluster source code it seems that no-delay is default.

Any idea how to improve the performance?

**Edit:**

I've found a solution that works in my case so I'd like to share it in case anyone else faces the same issue.

The root cause of the problem is the number of roundtrips between client and Gluster server during execution of open/write/close sequence. I don't know exactly what is happening behind but timing measurements shows exactly that pattern. Now, the obvious idea would be to "pack" open/write/close sequence into a single write function. Roughly, the C prototype of such function would be:

`int write(const char* fname, const void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset)`

But, there is already such API function `glfs_h_anonymous_write` in libgfapi (thanks goes to Suomya from Gluster mailing group). Kind of hidden thing there is the file identifier which is not plain file name, but something of type `struct glfs_object`. Clients obtain an instance of such object through API calls `glfs_h_lookupat/glfs_h_creat`. The point here is that `glfs_object` representing filename is "stateless" in a sense that corresponding `inode` is left intact (not ref counted). One should think of `glfs_object` as plain filename identifier and use it as you would use filename (actually, `glfs_object` stores plain pointer to corresponding `inode` without ref counting it).

Finally, we should use `glfs_h_lookupat/glfs_h_creat` once and write many times to the file using `glfs_h_anonymous_write`.

That way I was able to append 64 bytes to 5000 files in **0.5 seconds**, which is 20 times faster than using mounted volume and open//write/close sequence.

Comment: Is it really fair to compare writing to a local filesystem such as `ext4` (that can never be rw-mounted on several hosts simultaneously) with a distributed filesystem that requires all sorts of complex lock synchronization overhead?

Comment: Ivica Siladic, have you been able to do a patch to the 3.7 Gluster Code base? I would like to do a test using less open/close.  If not, can you provide me with small guidance in which part of the code could be modified in gluster. I am not familiar with it.

Comment: You don't need to patch Gluster to get advantage of `glfs_h_anonymous_write `.  The sequence of code which you need is something like this:  
  
`glfs_object* fh = glfs_h_lookupat(...)`  
`glfs_h_anonymous_write(fh, ...)`  
  
The first line obtains handle `fh` which you use afterwards like FILE*, but the difference is that you don't need to open/close the corresponding file. You just write/read to a file using a handle to it obtained through `glfs_h_lookupat`.